# Correlation between occupational status and knowledge

Tags: correlation

I'd like to correlate such variables as: 
X- 1.Unemployed, 2.Student, 3.Employed, 4.Pensioner

Y- Knowledge marked as points from 0 - 16.

I want to see if any of these groups have tendency to score higher points from each other.
Which test should I use? Is there an online calculator I could put the data in?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment, so I am writing this as an answer instead.

Have you tried creating a [box plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) of your data? This would be a quick way to visually inspect wether or not the knowledge points of each group seem to be significantly different. I'm sure there are some tools to do this online, and it is also pretty straightforward in [Excel](https://www.contextures.com/excelboxplotchart.html).